# Render private image on twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I have a content type with a private image field. I would like to render the image on the twig template in order to show it to the user when it has enough permission, but the image source is a private directory and I don't know what could be the path to show it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you would configure the formatted output of an image field in the content type and then render it in the node template:

```
{{ content.field_image }}
{{ content|without('field_image') }}
```

If you want to access the path of a private file directly then use the file scheme `private://`:

```
{{ file_url('private://foo.jpg') }}
```